# How to prove that two Groups Isomorphic?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

We know that when two groups are cyclic and have the same order then these two groups are isomorphic. 
If we know that one Group is cyclic and the other is not and they have the same order could we say that they are not isomorphic to each other?

Comment: Suppose that such a isomorphism exists, say $f:X\to Y$ ! You have $X$ to be cyclic. Then can you show that the $Y$ is cyclic too!

Comment: For your second question, $\mathbb{Z}_{6}$ and $S_{6}$ are not isomorphic.

Comment: yes, I know that I should prove that there is f which is homomorphism and Bijection. But I think we could say that two groups are Isomorphic if they have the same order and they are cyclic.

Comment: So could we use that as a proof that they are not Isomorphic? For example, if I have the  Unit group of  Z/8 which is not cyclic and the unit group of z/5 which is cyclic they both have the same order 4 so could we say that they are not isomorphic?

Answer (score 1):

Note that if $a$ is the generator of a cyclic group,i.e. $G=\langle a\rangle$, then $\phi(G)=\langle \phi(a)\rangle$, for any homomorphism $\phi$.

Comment: so the second group must be cyclic?

Comment: If it is an isomorphism then the second group is same as $\phi(G)$, and hence cyclic.

Comment: I do not know if they are an isomorphism. I just know the groups and I found that one of them is cyclic and the other not and they have the order 4.

Comment: My groups are the unit group of Z/8 and the unit group of Z/5

Comment: I showed that any group isomorphic to a cyclic group has to be cyclic.

Answer (score 1):

"If we know that one Group is cyclic, say $C_4$, and the other is not, say $C_2\times C_2$, and they have the same order, namely $4$, could we say that they are not isomorphic to each other?" Yes, we could.
The property of being cyclic, or abelian (or being nilpotent, solvable etc.),is preserved under isomorphism. The idea of an "isomorphism" is, that *all* "algebraic" properties are preserved.